# Disable "Make new folder" in Select Folder Dialog

Tags: vbscript

I'm making a script that uses the dialog box below to select the folder where this run commands the problem is that it is not necessary as an option to create a new folder ... I wonder how can I remove the "make new folder"?

[image]

**My Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim strPath

strPath = SelectFolder( "" )
If strPath = vbNull Then
    WScript.Echo "Cancelled"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Selected Folder: """ & strPath & """"
End If


Function SelectFolder( myStartFolder )

    ' Standard housekeeping
    Dim objFolder, objItem, objShell

    ' Custom error handling
    On Error Resume Next
    SelectFolder = vbNull

    ' Create a dialog object
    Set objShell  = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder", 1, myStartFolder )

    ' Return the path of the selected folder
    If IsObject( objfolder ) Then SelectFolder = objFolder.Self.Path

    ' Standard housekeeping
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objshell  = Nothing
    On Error Goto 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When in doubt, read [the](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> **BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON** (0x00000200)
>
> 0x00000200. Version 6.0. Do not include the **New Folder** button in the browse dialog box.

Add 0x200 to the options parameter:

```
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder", &h201, myStartFolder)
```